# Which is correct: 'that type always does' or that type always do'?

Tags: grammaticality

Is 'type' considered singular or plural in this case? Should I use 'do' or 'does' The spell check take either.

Comment: It could be either one, depending on what the actual nouns are. I.e, "this type" of **what**? You're almost always safe with singular, though.

Answer (score 4):

In British English (but not American English), collective nouns like *team*, *government* and even *bank* can take a singular or a plural verb, depending on whether the sense is about the individuals that make up the collective or the collective as a whole.

While *type* isn't obviously a collective like that, to my ears it seems to work the same way, and I would find nothing odd in

> That type always do.

meaning

> People of that type always do.

Comment: +1 To be clear, to the average American audience, the "do" version would sound like a mistake.

Comment: To be more clear, the form of agreement Colin mentions is often called 'notional' or 'logical' agreement, and whilst the US / UK 'divide' has some relevance, there are people on both sides of the Atlantic who prefer to use it. It cannot be labelled 'incorrect' (and 'British English' is a misnomer).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: your "there are people ... who prefer" sounds like a grudging "OK, I suppose it's all right then". I can't speak of the status of the form in North America, except for the disapproval I've read, but I assure you that in British English (I don't know why you refer to that as a 'misnomer') it is normal and doesn't raise an eyebrow.

Comment: I am British. I always use notional concord; I find it sounds more natural most of the time. 'British English' is ill-defined (check the 'definitions' on offer: eg [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_American_and_British_English) hedges with 'British English and American English, which, for the purposes of these articles, are defined as follows:') and certainly suggests a universality that is not warranted in at least some areas (eg punctuation around quotes).

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_English) also has, as regards agreement following collective nouns: '[O]ther sources, such as BBC Online and The Times style guides, recommend a strict noun-verb agreement with the collective noun always governing the verb conjugated in the singular. BBC radio news, however, insists on the plural verb.'

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the singular to apply i.e. 'That type always does.'

The alternative sounds as wrong as 'the spell check take either' - but I'm just being a bit naughty, I'm sure it was a typo!

Answer (score 0):

The **crew is** preparing to dock the ship.

This sentence is referring to the *individual* efforts of each *crew* member.

The usage of *do/does* would depend on what "type" of "type" you are referring to.

Type 1 - i.e., an Unit/individual, singular

Type 2 - all units/group, plural

Refer to: ["Do" vs. "does" with multiple singular subjects](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30575/do-vs-does-with-multiple-singular-subjects)

The Gregg Reference Manual provides excellent explanations of subject-verb agreement (section 10: 1001).