# "Do" vs. "does" with both singular and plural subjects

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I know multiple singular subjects have been addressed [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/30575/60477) and singular compound subjects [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117346/agreement-with-compound-subjects-joined-by-and). However, I came across a sentence with multiple subjects, one single paired with one plural. I could not find this question addressed. For example

> *Does a table and four chairs sound like sufficient furniture for a breakfast room?*

That doesn't quite sound right to me, but then

> *Do a table and four chairs sound like sufficient furniture for a breakfast room?*

also sounds a bit off. Which would be correct? Or are both incorrect?

Purdue uni [subject-verb agreement](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/subject_verb_agreement.html) is confusing.

Comment: 'Does/Do an apple and oranges taste good to you?' is infelicitous, pairing indefinite and plural generics. I've amended the example.

Comment: Is there a real linguistic need to write a clunky sentence(s) like this?

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ No. It's not my sentence. I came across it in a course and it got me curious.

Comment: Could you please cite your source?

Comment: I'd rather not be specific, but it's an online course by an ASU extension.

Comment: Actually, we are kind of big on "specific" here....the suggested edits may actually skirt your intent. Your post will go automatically on the re-open queue once you show some context and basic research. BTW...just to get the ball rolling, I added some accredited copy/pasta

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ I'm not sure what you're looking for. The linked answers do not address the specific question and thus are clearly not duplicates. Related? Yes. Duplicates? No. Searches yield only addressing this topic in reference to single objects. If you know of a good grammar site, please link it and I'll answer it myself if I can find this addressed.

Comment: I'm sorry we could not help you out...are the edited samples not working for you? We can "roll-back" the changes, but the samples you had would not really work as they were written.

Comment: The edited samples are accurate in that they form a compound subject of a singular subject and a plural subject. The linked answers do not answer the specific question.

Comment: This should be re-opened, the last link removed from the question, then added as an answer, with the appropriate text quoted, *When the subject of a sentence is composed of two or more nouns or pronouns connected by and, use a plural verb.* Meaning, the second quote is correct, if a bit awkward.

Comment: We are still waiting one more user review.